# Running virtualbox/vagrant in a cloud instance

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I've tried two things:

First, I tried to install virtualbox on a EC2 machine, which proved to be impossible.

Second, I was able to install both vagrant and virtualbox on a Digital Ocean droplet, but when I tried to run `vagrant up`, it got stuck on `Booting VM`.

Several sources on Internet say that it is not possible to run a VM inside a virtualized environment (both Amazon and Digital Ocean provide this).

Is there any way I can solve this with another provider, or is there a way to run vagrant/virtualbox in Amazon or Digital Ocean?

Comment: why do you specifically want to run virtual box on AWS? AWS has an [import](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-instance-import.html) feature so you can import your VBox VM and create s a new ec2 instance

Comment: @FrédéricHenri To be more specific, I want to run a Blackboard Learn instance (https://community.blackboard.com/docs/DOC-1649). Unfortunately, the image is a `.box`, so it seems I can't use the AWS import feature

Answer (score 1):

1. Install VirtualBox and Vagrant on a physical machine such as your desktop
2. Run the 3 commands from the command line:
3. vagrant init somenameyoumakeup file://urlToYour.box
4. vagrant up
5. vagrant halt
6. Open the VirtualBox UI
7. Export the Virtual machine to OVA format using the File -> Export menu
8. Follow the guide here for importing an OVA: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/